# How to generate normal coordinate?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm developping an game using the API opengl es 2.0. I need to know how to generate the normal coordinate because i need them to developp the lighting.
I'm wondering if there is a software or an algorithm that generate normal coordinate.
Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normals are not coordinates but vectors.
The normal of a plane is the cross product of two vectors that lie on that plane.

Given three coordinates (say a,b,c) on a plane, you can calculate the normal by;

(b - a) X (c - a)

Wiki link : [CrossProduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)